# WPCLI search and replace variants for all tables

Tags: wp-cli

What is the difference between:

```
wp search-replace 'http://' 'https://' --allow-root
```

to:

```
wp search-replace 'http://' 'https://' --all-tables-with-prefix --allow-root
```

AFAIU, the first search and replace in all tables without prefix and the second in all tables --- with or without prefix.

Is that correct?

I ask this after I got much more tables with the second command, yet the syntax seem a bit confusing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a WordPress installation, a certain number of database tables are registered in the `$wpdb` object. To see what they are, you can run the WP-CLI command `wp db tables`.

On my local WP installation, these are the `$wpdb`-registered tables:

```
wp_users
wp_usermeta
wp_posts
wp_comments
wp_links
wp_options
wp_postmeta
wp_terms
wp_term_taxonomy
wp_term_relationships
wp_termmeta
wp_commentmeta
wp_blogs
wp_signups
wp_site
wp_sitemeta
wp_sitecategories
wp_registration_log
wp_blog_versions
```

The WordPress table prefix, by default, is `wp_`. You can change this in your `wp-config.php` file, and might choose to do this for any number of reasons: maybe you need to run multiple WordPress installations from a single database, or perhaps you want to harden your WordPress installation by making certain things harder for an attacker to guess.

Plugins and/or themes might create new tables in the WordPress database: for example, Gravity Forms generates a bunch of tables in the format `{$wpdb->prefix}_rg_{table_name}` (so, in the default WordPress installation, `wp_rg_{table_name}`). When you run `wp search-replace {search} {replace}`, these other tables *will not be searched*, because the `$wpdb` object doesn't know about them.

To search these non-`$wpdb`-registered tables that still have the WordPress table prefix (ie, `wp_` or whatever you've set it to), you use the `--all-tables-with-prefix` flag on the `wp search-replace` invocation.

If you want to search *all* the tables in your database, *regardless* of their prefix, you can use the `--all-tables` flag. Be careful, though, as this may have unintended consequences (in a Multisite environment, for example, or in the case where you have multiple WordPress installations running from a single database).

As an aside, I *strongly* recommend using the `--dry-run` flag for each search & replace that you do, so you can see what will be affected *before* you make changes to your database.

### References

- [`wp search-replace`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/)
- [`wp db tables`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/tables/)